# What is causing CentOS 5.5 to crash reproducibly when browsing to some sites?

Tags: firefox, centos, xorg, nvidia-quadro

I have a problem that is crashing my GUI all the way back out to the login prompt in CentOS.

It seems to be reproducible, but not 100% of the time. Basically if I go to Youtube and search for something, click on the first result, it crashes. But some stuff loads fine - like the featured videos on the front page.

I am using firefox 3.6.13.

What can I check? I already tried to add something this guy suggested:

http://fossplanet.com/f11/%5Bcentos%5D-solved-annoying-firefox-crash-nvidia-16325/

My video card is a Nvidia QuadroFX 550

Comment: When the system crashes to your login prompt, do you mean graphical login prompt, or text login prompt?

Comment: I see the text login prompt briefly, then it automatically comes back to the graphical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would check the xorg logs. It sounds to me like maybe flash is crashing your gnome session (unless you are running kde).

I have had crashing problems with gnome before where it would do the same thing (log out to prompt). Take a look in the logs for gnome as well.

Comment: So after doing some digging, I had to add some module load paths to the xorg file because in the log there was an error loading the GLX modules, which was coming from the X conf not nvidia